# Convert list of NaNs and strings to int?

Tags: python

I have the following list in Python:

```
mylist = [float('NaN'), u'2', u'3', u'1', u'4', u'1/2', u'2/3', u'0']
```

I want to convert everything to an int. I want the strings with a slash in to take the first value.

This is what I've tried:

```
newlist = [int(str(x).split('/')[0]) for x in mylist]
```

But this doesn't work on the `NaN` value. What is the best way to handle both the strings and the `NaN` value?

Comment: You want NaN to be converted to an int. So what int do you want NaN to be converted to?

Comment: @khelwood: One could just as well ask what float it should be, but it is indeed a float.

Comment: @zondo One could, but it is already a float, and he's trying to convert it to an int.

Comment: @khelwood: My point is that NaN doesn't make sense as a float, but it is anyway.  I don't see why it is strange that the OP thought it might also be an integer.

Comment: @zondo I didn't say it was strange. I asked the OP to clarify what they wanted to do.

Comment: thanks all. I'd like NaN to be converted to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution with [`pandas.isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

mylist = [np.nan, u'2', u'3', u'1', u'4', u'1/2', u'2/3', u'0']

newList = [0 if pd.isnull(item) else int(str(item).split('/')[0]) for item in mylist]
print(newList)
[0, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 2, 0]
```

Pandas solution with replace `NaN` to `'0'` by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html), spliting by [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html), get first element of lists by `str[0]` and casting by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
mylist = [np.nan, u'2', u'3', u'1', u'4', u'1/2', u'2/3', u'0']

newList = pd.Series(mylist).fillna('0').str.split('/').str[0].astype(int)
print(newList)
0    0
1    2
2    3
3    1
4    4
5    1
6    2
7    0
dtype: int32

print(newList.tolist())
[0, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 2, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the isnan function in the maths library to check if a float is NaN, however it takes float as an argument, so you'll have to first convert your items into float. You can choose whether to skip the NaN, or save them as some default value. In the code below the NaN's are saved as int 0

```
import math

mylist = [float('NaN'), u'2', u'3', u'1', u'4', u'1/2', u'2/3', u'0']

newlist = []

for item in mylist:

    x = float(str(item).split('/')[0])

    if not math.isnan(x):
        newlist.append(int(x))
    else:
        newlist.append(0)

print newlist
```

Answer (score 0):

We know, that  **NaN is always != NaN**.
 
Use the following approach *to convert everything to integer*:

```
mylist = [float('NaN'), u'2', u'3', u'1', u'4', u'1/2', u'2/3', u'0']
newList = [0 if (not item or (item != item)) else int(str(item).split('/')[0]) for item in mylist]
print(newList)
```

The output:

```
[0, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 2, 0]
```